# Spring security No bean named 'CustomAuthenticationProvider' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want go get spring security authentication form. Here part of spring-security.xml file

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="com.portal.framework.web.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login/validate" />
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="usernameOrEmail" />
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

I got error: 
No bean named 'customAuthenticationProvider' is defined

The beans resolution is done by Java configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.portal"})
public class MainConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }
}
```

Is it any problem with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/someXmlfile.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

with

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.portal.configuration.IntegrationServerWebConfig
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And defining the class:

```
@Configuration

@ImportResource({
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml",
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml"})

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.portal"})
public class IntegrationServerWebConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML config should define which package to scan for additional components. You can do that like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

</beans>
```